# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands/'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i am getting this error output, when i want to use discord:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands/'
←[90m    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:1021:3)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DAA23\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\main.js:11:25)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  errno: ←[33m-4058←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'scandir'←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  path: ←[32m'./commands/'←[39m
}
```

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    const prefix = '*';
    const fs = require('fs');

    client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => 
    file.endsWith('.js'));

    for(const file of commandFiles){
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }


    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('ur bot is on');
    });

    client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) ||message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'loop'){
        message.channel.send('-loop');
    };

});

client.login('xxxxx.xxxxxx');
```

So I am trying to create a discord bot and previously it said cannot find discord.js so I did 'npm install discord.js' and that removed the discord error however it introduced this error and I don't know how to fix it. I have tried reinstalling nodejs and also reinstalling discord but nothing has changed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! From quickly overflying this error it looks like there might be an error in your `main.js` file. Can you include your project structure ? And some code ?

Comment: Sure I have added my main.js code underneath the error

Comment: The error means you are trying to use `readdirSync` on `./commands` but it can't find the directory. Can you include your project structure / folder structure ?

Comment: What do you mean by folder structure? Do you want the directory of main.js or something else?  sorry if this is really basic but I just started and I am trying to learn.

Comment: Yeah how does the folder structure of your project look like ? The root folder ? What files and folders do you have ?

Comment: This is the directory    C:\Users\DAA23\OneDrive\Desktop\bot     and the folder inside is node_modules and the files inside are: main.js  , package.json  , package-lock.json  there are also numerous folders inside node_modules. I have also checked with the terminal in Microsoft Visual Code and the error says:   errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './commands/'
}    also in the debug terminal it says : Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you gave me I think your just missing the `commands` directory. In your code you are trying to read files in the `commands` directory, but since it does not exist it throws the error.

I assume your project structure looks like this (bases on your comment)

```bash
/
  node_modules/
  main.js
  package.json
```

If you are trying to read the files inside a directory called `commands` from within the `main.js` file, you need to actually create the directory first. So your structure should look like this

```bash
/
  node_modules/
  commands/
  main.js
  package.json
```

Then to read the files inside the commands directory you can try this

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const files = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'commands'));
```

Comment: Yes you were correct, I rewrote the file and I was missing a 'commands folder' thank you for help and your time.