# "No such file or directory, scandir './command/'"

Tags: discord.js

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QitjJ.png)

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEmtE.png)

Please help me fix this, I'm desperately trying to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65858441/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-scandir-commands)

Comment: You have a directory `command` but your code is trying to find `commands`. Change code or rename directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply getting this error because in your `main.js` file, you are expecting the commands to be in the `./commands` folder while all the commands are actually in the `./command` folder without an s. So all you have to do is either change your command folder's name to `commands` or you can edit your `main.js` file and change the command folder's name to `./command` like this:

```js
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./command/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I will recommend you using glob for command handler `npm i glob`
With this code you can have file tree like this:

- Folder

  - File in folder
- File not in folder

And it will still work well

```js
const { glob } = require('glob')
const { promisify } = require('util');

const globPromise = promisify(glob);

const dir = await globPromise(`${process.cwd()}/commands/**/*.js`);

dir.map((x) => {
    const file = require(x)

    if(file.name) {
        client.commands.set(file.name, file)
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

mb u can print "command", not "commandS"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).